# Deploying 3rd party packages to my internal repo using maven using custom wagon

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-3, wagon

How can i use my own wagon to deploy 3rd party packages to my remote repository?

For example i can deploy a 3rd party package without altering pom.xml using the following command.

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=thirdparty::default::http://myremoserver.com/mavenrepository/thirdparty -f thirpartpomfile -Dmaven.install.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

How can i tell maven to use a specific wagon for deploying packages? Can i pass some command line argument or add some entry to settings.xml?

How can i do the same for gradle?

Answer (score 2):

The "[Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)" only mention:

> First, the wagon-provider(`wagon-ftp`, `wagon-file`, etc..) must be placed to your `${maven.home}/lib`.

That is enough for you to use `mvn deploy-file` with other protocols.
Your own wagon should be copied there (`${maven.home}/lib`).

See [Maven Deploy File Plugin FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html):

> If you are using the deploy:deploy-file goal and encounter this error:
>
> ```
> Error deploying artifact: Unsupported Protocol: 'ftp': 
>   Cannot find wagon which supports the requested protocol: ftp"
> ```
>
> Then you need to place the appropriate wagon provider in your %M2_HOME%/lib.

If the error description is something like this:

> ```
> Error deploying artifact: Unsupported Protocol: 'ftp': 
>   Cannot find wagon which supports the requested protocol: 
>     ftp org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP"
> ```
>
> Then you need to place the **`commons-net`** jar in `%M2_HOME%/lib`.

With Gradle, you can do the same, but with the [Maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html), delegating the deploy-file to maven, since the [Maven Deployer plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html?_ga=2.264477007.1179496055.1494684440-387322762.1494684440#uploading_to_maven_repositories) might not support custom protocols.